Java - Reverse engineer a file generated by protocol buffer
I am new to Springboot. I recently joined a springboot project, and I saw a java file.
package org.thingsboard.server.controller.tts;// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: my_attributes.proto

// Protobuf Java Version: 3.25.1
public final class MyAttributesOuterClass {
  private MyAttributesOuterClass() {}
  public static void registerAllExtensions(
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite registry) {
  }

  public static void registerAllExtensions(
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
    registerAllExtensions(
        (com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite) registry);
  }
  /**
   * <pre>
   * Enum of device types
   * </pre>
   *
   * Protobuf enum {@code DeviceType}
   */

…

What I am trying to do is, to add a new field for this class, but I have no idea how to do it in a right way.
I tried to search for my_attributes.proto, but it doesn’t exist in the project.
There is a dependency for protobuf
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

So I wonder if anyone has a way to find out the source of this file, and how this file is generated initially, or how to reverse engineer this file etc.
Update:
pom.xml on the root
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--
                          The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
                          protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
                          protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
                        -->
                        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                        </protocArtifact>
                        <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


Do you have any .proto files in your project? Also look for protobuf-maven-plugin in your pom.xml. It may contain path to your proto files.

@talex please check my update above. I have protobuf-maven-plugin but it doesn't contain any path

Look in parent pom.xml

@talex please check my update above

Now you have to look for proto files in dependencies :)

@talex I still couldn't find anything

Last thing you can try is debugging. Put breakpoint in org.xolstice.maven.plugin.protobuf.AbstractProtocMojo#execute and look for value of derivedProtoPathElements.

Or you can choose easy road and ask your colleagues for help :)

By default proto files are located in src/main/proto/.
Can be overwritten by protoSourceRoot configuration property.
It also looks in dependencies for proto files.
Quote from JavaDoc
/**
 * This mojo executes the {@code protoc} compiler for generating main Java sources
 * from protocol buffer definitions. It also searches dependency artifacts for
 * {@code .proto} files and includes them in the {@code proto_path} so that they can be
 * referenced. Finally, it adds the {@code .proto} files to the project as resources so
 * that they are included in the final artifact.
 */


no I don't have /proto folder

no protoSourceRoot found in the project
